# touchdown held down libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Is there an equivalent in libGdx (in Android) like the touchdown event - so when a user touches the screen (and holds their finger down continuously),i.e. touchhelddown method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`GestureDetector`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#c5txscj0tnc/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.java&q=gesturedetector%20package:http://libgdx%5C.googlecode%5C.com). It implements `InputAdapter` so you can use it instead of your InputAdapter or along with your InputAdapter using `InputMultiplexer`.

You need to provide a `GestureListener` to it. GestureDetector calls GestureListener's methods when it detects supported gestures. These methods and gestures are:

```
public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer);
public boolean tap (int x, int y, int count);
public boolean longPress (int x, int y);
public boolean fling (float velocityX, float velocityY);
public boolean pan (int x, int y, int deltaX, int deltaY);
public boolean zoom (float originalDistance, float currentDistance);
public boolean pinch (Vector2 initialFirstPointer, Vector2 initialSecondPointer, 
                      Vector2 firstPointer, Vector2 secondPointer);
```

You can extend `GestureAdapter` and override the method you are interested in. In your case you will override `longPress` method. You can also provide `longPressDuration` as a parameter to constructor.

Comment: still finding it a bit funky extending the GestureAdapter, being a noobie would you be able to post an example of how to do this properly, I'm getting odd results!  I want to scale a sprite during the long press duration and then it falls back to the original size after the press is released.